# How to convert audio file of type G.723.1 into wav format?

Tags: audio, codec, sox, audio-conversion

I have few audio files which have `.wav` extension. I tried to get information about this file using `soxi <foo.wav>` command but I got following error :

> soxi FAIL formats: can't open input file foo.wav':
>   Unknown WAV file encoding (type a100)

So I used `MediaInfo` tool to get more information about this file I got following information about this file:

> **General**
>
> Format                : Wave
>
> File size             : 51.4 KiB
>
> Duration              : 1mn 18s Overall
>
> bit rate              : 5 339 bps
>
> **Audio**
>
> Format          : G.723.1
>
> Codec ID              : A100
>
> Duration              : 1mn 18s
>
> Bit rate              : 5 328 bps
>
> Channel(s)            : 1 channel
>
> Sampling rate         : 8 000 Hz
>
> Stream size           : 51.3 KiB (100%)

According to this information it seems like this file is has `G.723.1` format and SOX is not able to understand this format.

So I would like to know :

- My conclusion that SOX does not support this type of file is correct?
- If SOX does not support this type of file then installing some codec will help? I have seen `lame` command on few web pages but not sure if it will help me or not.

Request super users to help !

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, SoX doesn’t support G.723.1. Installing an optional package won’t help either.

As Jet said, FFmpeg should be able to read the file (according to the [list of supported audio codecs](http://ffmpeg.org/general.html#Audio-Codecs)). If you just want to convert the audio to a different format, this should do it:

```
ffmpeg -i foo.wav -c some_codec -f some_format output_file_name
```

You can view a list of supported codecs and formats with `ffmpeg -codecs` and `ffmpeg -formats`, respectively.

If you want to do some further processing with SoX, you can use FFmpeg to decode it and pipe the result into SoX like this:

```
ffmpeg -i foo.wav -f sox - | sox -p output_file_name effects ...
```

Comment: You just added some extra info to @Jet's answer. You could just edit his answer, because he wrote it before you...

Answer (score 2):

I think [FFMpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) will help you. It's free (and open-source).
And it's available for Windows and Unixoids.
It can convert almost all known types of audio/video/graphics.